# Javascript code execution delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I have called my below function on the click event.
Basically this code takes some time (approximately 200ms) to execute on the browser because of I am triggering click event on the jquery tree.

```
function showAsset()
{
      $(".err").html("Please wait . . .")
      $(".err").css('display','block')
      $(".err").css('background','orange')
      v=$("#asset_details").val()
      v=v.split("###")
      v1=v[0].split("-")
//Upto this block should be executed first

      //Jquery Tree block starts
      $("#navigation ."+v1+" div").click()
      $("#navigation ."+v[1]+" div").click()
      $("#navigation table tr:contains('"+v[0]+"')").css({'background':'#FFF82A'})
       $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' :( $("#navigation table tr:contains('"+v[0]+"')").position().top-5)
    });
       //Jquery Tree block ends
}
```

So to instrut my users about this loading, I am showing "please wait . . ." message at start of the function call.
But this message is showing after full execution of the function call.

My question is why the start of the block also gets delayed when i call this function.
I placed the Jquery Tree block at the bottom of the function. But overall code is executed at the same time.

Is there any way to separate this execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to separate your execution.

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

[*source*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

The first block without `setTimeout` is executed and after the `setTimeout` is executed in separate scope.

```js
function showAsset() {
  $(".err").html("Please wait . . .")
  $(".err").css('display', 'block')
  $(".err").css('background', 'orange')
  v = $("#asset_details").val()
  v = v.split("###")
  v1 = v[0].split("-")
    //Upto this block should be executed first

  //Jquery Tree block starts

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#navigation ." + v1 + " div").click()
    $("#navigation ." + v[1] + " div").click()
    $("#navigation table tr:contains('" + v[0] + "')").css({
      'background': '#FFF82A'
    })
    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': ($("#navigation table tr:contains('" + v[0] + "')").position().top - 5)
    });
    //Jquery Tree block ends
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Its working for me thanks. Added interval to 80, as 0 has the same result